# Return keyword in PowerShell - output not formatted correctly

Tags: powershell

Consider this simple code:

```
function Fruits {
    Install-WindowsFeature -Name Telnet-Client

    return @("apple", "banana", "orange")
}

$FruitArray = @(Fruits)
```

Output of `$FruitArray[0]`:

```
Success Restart Needed Exit Code     Feature Result
------- -------------- ---------     --------------
True    Yes            Success       {}
```

Output of `$FruitArray[1], $FruitArray[2], $FruitArray[3]`:

```
apple
banana
orange
```

What is happening here? How can I clear the unwanted output from the first element of the array, using `return`?

Using PowerShell version 5.1, Server 2012 R2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the unexpected output because `Install-WindowsFeature` returns an object.

If you don't care about the result of `Install-WindowsFeature` you can pipe the result to `null` like this:

```
Install-WindowsFeature -Name Telnet-Client *> $null
```

Comment: For the sake of completion, there's also the `Out-Null` cmdlet. The above line would then become `Install-WindowsFeature -Name Telnet-Client | Out-Null`

Answer (score 0):

It is formatted properly, have a  look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_return?view=powershell-6)

From the link (emphasis mine):

> The Return keyword exits a function, script, or script block. It can be used to exit a scope at a specific point, to return a value, or to indicate that the end of the scope has been reached.
>
> Users who are familiar with languages like C or C# might want to use the Return keyword to make the logic of leaving a scope explicit.
>
> **In PowerShell, the results of each statement are returned as output, even without a statement that contains the Return keyword. Languages like C or C# return only the value or values that are specified by the Return keyword.**
>
> Blockquote